# python ghostscript Popen cannot find file

Tags: python, ghostscript

```
import ghostscript
import sys, subprocess,os
output = subprocess.Popen(['gs', '-dSAFER', '-dNOPAUSE', '-dBATCH', '-sDEVICE=tiffg4', '-g6120x7920 ','-r720x720','-sOutputFile=C:\Python25\pdfmining\page_%03d.tif' 'C:\Python25\pdfmining\ae.pdf'])
```

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified, 
with a call to line 3 in the program above.  I know i am missing something really simple here, related to Popen i believe, anyone see what is causing this and why I am getting can't find file?

Comment: What are you importing ``ghostscript`` for? You don't use it in your example.

Comment: There is a comma missing between the last two elements in the arguments list.

Comment: isn't the gs calling the ghostscript?

Comment: With ``import`` you get objects and functions into your program that you can use, like ``os.mkdir`` or ``sys.path``. But you never use ``ghostscript.<something>``. The ``'gs'`` in your call to subprocess.Popen is an **external** program that has nothing to do with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `shell=True` parameter to Popen. I believe this will involve the shell path for executable programs.

Answer (score 0):

For windows install ghostscript and set the path in enviornment variables and execute the following command.

command = ["gswin32c",
               "-q",
               "-g%dx%d" % size,
               "-dNOPAUSE -dSAFER",
               "-sDEVICE=ppmraw",
               "-sOutputFile=%s" % file 
              ]

command = string.join(command)

gs = os.popen(command, "w")